# How to call one function after another in Chrome Extension content script

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension

I have two functions injectChat and firstTimeTrigger in my content script. Both of them attach a script to the body of the DOM.

I need injectChat to run first and after it's fully complete then load firstTimeTrigger. firstTimeTrigger doesn't work unless injectChat run and is fully loaded.

These are the two functions -

```
function injectChat(){
    console.log("Injecting Chat");

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.setAttribute("src", `${host}/api/botpress-platform-webchat/inject.js/`);
    script.setAttribute("id", 'botpress-script');
    document.body.appendChild(script);

    script.addEventListener('load', function(){
        const botpress_settings = `window.botpressWebChat.init({host: '${host}'})`;
        const settings = document.createElement('script');
        settings.setAttribute("id", "botpress-settings");
        settings.innerHTML = botpress_settings;
        document.body.appendChild(settings);

    });

};

function firstTimeTrigger(){
    console.log("First Time Trigger");
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: "isFirstTime"}, function(response) {
        if(response == true){
            const botpress_trigger_1 = "window.botpressWebChat.sendEvent({ type: 'show' })";
            const botpress_trigger_2 = `window.botpressWebChat.sendEvent({ type: 'proactive-trigger', platform: 'web', text: '${JSON.stringify(config)}' })`;
            const trigger = document.createElement('script');
            trigger.innerHTML = botpress_trigger_1 + '\n' + botpress_trigger_2;
            document.body.appendChild(trigger);
        }   
    }); 
};
```

Currently, I've been doing it like this

```
injectChat();
setTimeout(function(){
   firstTimeTrigger();
}, 3000);
```

But it's very unreliable because of the various page load times due to this being inside a content script.

How do I make this happen? Promises don't work in here.

Comment: Looks like the `firstTimeTrigger()` function will trigger only once after the `injectChat()` completed. Why don't you merge `firstTimeTrigger()` at the end of `injectChat()` ?

Comment: Yeah I wish. It just doesn't work

Answer (score 0):

You can pass `firstTimeTrigger` inside of `injectChat` as a parameter and call it at the end of the function, like this:

```
function injectChat(firstTimeTrigger) {
  // logic of the injectChat function...
  firstTimeTrigger();
}
```

Comment: That doesn't work because the function is called before the body of injectChat gets loaded.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to Javascript's [callback hell](http://callbackhell.com/) :)

In order to run a function after the previous script has finished, you have to call it at the end of the script's `load` event. Remember to set up the `load` listener **before** actually adding the script element to the page. For example:

```
function injectChat(){
    console.log('Injecting Chat');

    const script = document.createElement('script');
    script.setAttribute('type','text/javascript');
    script.setAttribute('src', `${host}/api/botpress-platform-webchat/inject.js/`);
    script.setAttribute('id', 'botpress-script');   
    script.addEventListener('load', injectSettings);  //set up the load listener ...

    document.body.appendChild(script);  //...before adding the script element to the page
}

function injectSettings(){
    console.log('Injecting settings');

    const settings = document.createElement('script');
    settings.setAttribute('id', 'botpress-settings');
    settings.innerHTML = `window.botpressWebChat.init({host: '${host}'})`;
    settings.addEventListener('load', firstTimeTrigger); //set up listener...

    document.body.appendChild(settings);  //...before injecting code
}

function firstTimeTrigger(){
    console.log('First Time Trigger');
    chrome.runtime.sendMessage({type: 'isFirstTime'}, function(response) {
        if(response == true){

            const trigger = document.createElement('script');
            trigger.innerHTML = `
                window.botpressWebChat.sendEvent({ type: 'show' });
                window.botpressWebChat.sendEvent({ type: 'proactive-trigger', platform: 'web', text: ${JSON.stringify(config)} });
            `;
            document.body.appendChild(trigger);
        }   
    }); 
}

injectChat();
```